# Can't select ListView's item with setFocusableInTouchMode(true)

Tags: android-listview, android

I'v been stucked with such common problem but I can't still solve it. When my application's activity started, device is in touch mode by default.

I want to implement selection of some listview item, when user taps some button and use the following code for it:

```
... 
                // my activity, inside onCreate()
                myListView.setFocusable(true);
                myListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                button.setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            myListView.setSelection(specifiedPosition);
                        }
                    }
                );
                ...
```

But even with this logic ListView just set specified item to the top of itself and doesn't highlight them.

I also try to use requestFocus() but it didn't help me. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: setSelection doesn't do what you want - it means a different thing.

According to the setSelection documentation:

> If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be
>   positioned appropriately.

That's why you see the positioning.

Also see the Touch Mode documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html

> **In touch mode, there is no focus and no selection.** Any selected item
>   in a list of in a grid becomes unselected as soon as the user enters
>   touch mode. Similarly, any focused widgets become unfocused when the
>   user enters touch mode. The image below illustrates what happens when
>   the user touches a list after selecting an item with the trackball.

---

For possible solutions see the following post:
[Highlight ListView selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058291/highlight-listview-selected-row)