# MvvmCross: What is the best way to get the selected item from an MvxListView in android?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross v3.06 and I've defined a MvxListView in android which is bound to a list. I can see the list but can't work out the best way to get hold of the item that is selected when I click it.

At the moment I'm doing the following in the OnCreate of the activity but it's not particularly MVVM and I wondered if there is a better way through binding?

```
var list = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.subslist);
list.ItemClick = ((MyViewModel)ViewModel).ItemSelectedCommand;
```

I can't find any documentation on the best way to go about this so any help would be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For android, the most common technique is to bind `ItemClick` to an `MvxCommand<TItem>` - so use:

```
 local:MvxBind="ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"
```

You can see this in operation in examples including:

- DailyDilbert - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DailyDilbert/DailyDilbert.Droid/Resources/Layout/ListView.axml
- OldTutorial - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/OldTutorial/Tutorial.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/Page_MainMenuView.axml
- N=16 - Collect-A-Bull - see http://youtu.be/1PC5Q30FyR4?t=26m10s and https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-16-CollectABull-Part5/CollectABull.Droid/Resources/Layout/ListView.axml

---

Less common (so far), for Android, you can also bind to a custom binding `SelectedItem` on  `MvxListView`

This technique is shown on a `Spinner` (`MvxSpinner`) in MoreControls - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/MoreControls/MoreControls.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml (this example is constructed live during the N=18 video - see http://youtu.be/s1LhXdCTsn4?t=7m26s

Comment: Excellent, that's really useful. Many thanks Stuart, and compliments on your work on MvvmCross.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the SelectedItem feature to work for a MvxListView. I can see the databinding working, but the selected item highlights momentarily, and then the highlight disappears. Any ideas why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5058401/373321 for why Android discourages selection... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364907/how-to-highlight-the-selected-item-in-an-mvxlistview/18409625#18409625 for one user's approach