# How to highlight the selected item in an MvxListView

Tags: android, mvvmcross

How can I keep an item, in an `MvxListView`, highlighted until it is unselected or until another item is selected?

My program has an `MvxListView` that correctly displays a list of items.  The user can select an item, by clicking it, and then click a save button.  The selected item is stored in `MyChosenItem` until it is needed by the save button code.  Currently, the selected item stays highlights for a split second before returning to the unselected color.

This is how the `MvxListView` is created:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/MyMvxListViewControl"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems; SelectedItem MyChosenItem"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_item_layout" />
```

This is `Layout/my_item_layout.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project.Ui.Droid"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="300.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        local:MvxBind="Text Field1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        local:MvxBind="Text Field2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058291/highlight-listview-selected-row help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method provides an easy way to customize which items remain highlighted.  I settled on this because it gives me full control over what is highlighted and how it is displayed in the list.  (This example shows highlighting only one item, but it could easily be extended to highlight more.)

1. The MvxListView, in the original question, links to `MyItems` and `MyChosenItem` in the associated view model.  `MyItems` is a collection of `Item`, and `MyChosenItem` is just a single `Item`.  I added `isItemSelected` to `Item`.  The `Item` class looks like this now:

   ```
   public class Item : MvxViewModel           
   {
       private string _field1;
       private string _field2;
       private bool _isItemSelected = false;

       public string Field1
       {
           get { return _field1; }
           set
           {
               _field1= value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("Field1");
           }
       }

       public string Field2
       {
           get { return _field2; }
           set
           {
               _field2= value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("Field2");
           }
       }

       public bool isItemSelected
       {
           get { return _isItemSelected; }
           set
           {
               _isItemSelected = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("isItemSelected");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: The `Item` class extends `MvxViewModel` so that `RaisePropertyChange()` can be called.  This allows `my_item_layout.xaml` to be notified when that property changes.
2. Update each instance of `isItemSelected` from the property that the MvxListView's `SelectedItem` binds to.  In this case, that's the `MyChosenItem` property in the associated view model.  This is what the new code looks like:

   ```
   public Item MyChosenItem
   {
       get { return _myChosenItem; }
       set
       {
           if (_myChosenItem != value)
           {
               _myChosenItem = value;
               UpdateItemSelections();
               RaisePropertyChanged("MyChosenItem");
           }
       }
   }

   // Select MyChosenItem and unselect all other items
   private void UpdateItemSelections()
   {
       if( MyItems.Count > 0)
       {
           for (int index = 0; index < MyItems.Count; index++)
           {
               // If the chosen item is the same, mark it as selected
               if (MyItems[index].Field1.Equals(MyChosenItem.Field1)
                   && MyItems[index].Field2.Equals(MyChosenItem.Field2))
               {
                   MyItems[index].isItemSelected = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   // Only trigger the property changed event if it needs to change
                   if (MyItems[index].isItemSelected)
                   {
                       MyItems[index].isItemSelected = false;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   It would be pretty easy to modify `UpdateItemSelections()` to any selection behavior you want.
3. Make each row do something based on the `isItemSelected` property.  I just made the background change colors by controlling the visibility property of a view.  However, all sorts of things are possible.  `isItemSelected` could even be passed to a custom control for some really interesting visuals.  My new `Layout/my_item_layout.xaml` looks like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project.Ui.Droid"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <!-- SELECTED BACKGROUND COLOR -->
       <View
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           local:MvxBind="Visibility isItemSelected,Converter=BoolToViewStates" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="300.0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           local:MvxBind="Text Field1" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="250.0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           local:MvxBind="Text Field2" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

---

**EDIT**

It might be better to use an `MvxCommand` instead of triggering the highlighted action when the `SelectedItem` is set.  It seems the `SelectedItem` is only set if it is not already selected.  Tapping an item will select it.  Tapping another item will change the selection.  Tapping the same item again will **not** unselect it.  This means that once an item is selected, one item must remain selected.  If you need the ability to unselect all the items in the list, follow these modifications to the original instructions:

1. Add an `MvxCommand` to the view model.  Call `UpdateItemSelections()` from the `MvxCommand` instead of from `MyChosenItem`.

   ```
   public MvxCommand ItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

   // Constructor
   public ItemSelectionViewModel()
   {
       ItemSelectedCommand = new MvxCommand(OnItemSelected);
   }

   public Item MyChosenItem
   {
       get { return _myChosenItem; }
       set
       {
           if (_myChosenItem != value)
           {
               _myChosenItem = value;
               //UpdateItemSelections();    // Move this to OnItemSelected()
               RaisePropertyChanged("MyChosenItem");
           }
       }
   }

   private void OnItemSelected()
   {
       UpdateItemSelections();
   }
   ```
2. Change `UpdateItemSelections()` to toggle the `isItemSelected` property instead of always setting it to true:

   ```
   // Select MyChosenItem and unselect all other items
   private void UpdateItemSelections()
   {
       if( MyItems.Count > 0)
       {
           for (int index = 0; index < MyItems.Count; index++)
           {
               // If the chosen item is the same, mark it as selected
               if (MyItems[index].Field1.Equals(MyChosenItem.Field1)
                   && MyItems[index].Field2.Equals(MyChosenItem.Field2))
               {
                   // Toggle selected status
                   MyItems[index].isItemSelected = !MyItems[index].isItemSelected;
               }
               else
               {
                   // Only trigger the property changed event if it needs to change
                   if (MyItems[index].isItemSelected)
                   {
                       MyItems[index].isItemSelected = false;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Remember to check `MyChosenItem.isItemSelected == true` when saving or doing anything that acts on the selected item in the list.  There might be a value in `MyChosenItem` that is unselected in the list view the user sees.
4. Bind the `MvxCommand` to `ItemClick` in layout definition of the `MvxListView`:

   ```
   <Mvx.MvxListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="260dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
       android:id="@+id/MyMvxListViewControl"
       local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems; SelectedItem MyChosenItem; ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"
       local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_item_layout" />
   ```

Comment: Beware: the order of the bindings matters! First I had the ItemClick binding before the SelectedItem binding, didn't work. When i switched the two (SelectedItem followed by ItemClick) it all started to work.