# MvvmCross MvxTableLayout Events

Tags: android, xamarin, tablelayout, mvvmcross

MvxTableLayout does not seem to have any events.

Would it be possible to have an event for example, OnClickRow(r) where r is the row that got clicked? Having that would allow me to change the attributes of the TableRow itself, or of the individual TextViews(or whatever other control I've put in the ItemTemplate).

By attributes I mean background color, text color, font size etc.

What is the process of adding this event or any event by myself? 
(OK, Inheriting the MvxTableLayout would be the 1st step I guess).

TIA
Pap

Comment: In case it's not obvious from my question, I'm new to MVVMCross/Xamarin/Android but not new to C# & the .NET Framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `MvxTableLayout` is just an Android `TableLayout` with some binding added to allow it to be used with collections.

- Android TableLayout - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html
- Mvx Extensions - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxTableLayout.cs

`TableLayout` itself is a bit like a `Grid` in Wpf/SL. It's not really designed for large collections - it doesn't virtualise it's UI and it doesn't provide 'selection' type functionality.

You could add these hooks yourself if you wanted to - e.g. by providing callbacks from `Click` events on your table cells.

However, I suspect you might be better off going with a 'true' adapter-based layout - something like `MvxListView` or `MvxGridView`

- One user has written about highlighting in `MvxListView` in [How to highlight the selected item in an MvxListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364907/how-to-highlight-the-selected-item-in-an-mvxlistview/18409625#18409625)
- There are also ways to play with the Selected state using xml - e.g. see [Android ListView selected item stay highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted) (but use Xamarin's `ItemClick` method rather than Android's `SetOnItemClickListener`)

Comment: Thanks a ton Stuart. I'll check out all the info.

Comment: Is it true that GridView(and MvxGridView) gives me one cell per record in my database? If yes, is there a way to change this in MvxGridView so that one row of gridview cells "maps" to one record in my db? By the way I use the MvvmCross.SQLite plugin. Thanks