# How to select (highlight) an item in listveiw when click on button

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

How to highlight a specific row in `listview` when clicking a button, I could select an item inside `onItemClick` action using the code : `view.setSelected(true);` BUT, I want to select an item when clicking a `button` outside the `listview`

**edit**
I used this code :

```
lvData.setSelection(4);
lvData.setSelected(true);
```

where the xml selector is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

and the row layout is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtDuration"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the custom adapter is :

```
package com.example.heartbeats;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TrackAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Track> {

    private List<Track> values;
    private Context context;
    private int selectedItem = -1; // no item selected by default

    public ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

    public TrackAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Track> values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Keeps reference to avoid future findViewById()
        valuesViewHolder viewHolder;
        final Track t = values.get(position);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.row_track, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new valuesViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            viewHolder.tvDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);

            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/futura.ttf");
            viewHolder.tvTitle.setTypeface(type);
            viewHolder.tvDuration.setTypeface(type);

            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (valuesViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if (t != null) {
            viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(t.title);
            viewHolder.tvDuration.setText(t.duration);
        }

        return v;
    }


    public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    static class valuesViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDuration;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `listview.setItemChecked(position, true);`

Comment: @erakitin No it is not working !!

Comment: Also you should set choice mode for your ListView: `listview.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` or `listview.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

Comment: @erakitin it's listview.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

Comment: Okay, it seems the problem is in your list row layout. I think you will find answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058291/highlight-listview-selected-row).

Comment: What is your app `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can post answer, but I have to know your app's `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `selector.xml` file for that, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

In your `main.xml` file add below line to `ListView`:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
```