# Highlight a row with simple animation in an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a `ListView` with custom rows.  They have different background colors, set ind the `getView()` method of an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    bgResourceId = R.color.white;
    if (items.get(position).status.contentEquals("ok")) {
        bgResourceId = R.color.green;
    } else  items.get(position).status.contentEquals("error")) {
        bgResourceId = R.color.red;
    }
    row.setBackgroundResource(bgResourceId);
    return row;
}
```

Clicking on a row launches a new Activity. After finishing the new Actvity, we return to the Activity with the `ListView` and at his point I need to highlight one of the rows.

Inside the `onResume()` method, NOT after touching or clicking the row.
I do know which row (index) will get highlihgted.

Just a simple animation - maybe blink for one second, and after that, return to its original background color.
Something like this:

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: *Is that possible?* ... yes, it is

Comment: Follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058291/highlight-listview-selected-row) and add a custom animation on the view.

Comment: Thanks @Selvin, now, could you please tell me, how to do it?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. Please post your adapter code, including the code which assigns different background colors. And do tell us on what occasion you want the row to be highlighted - after an event (other than onTouch or onClick) or after a timer has finished or when? And also: do we know which row (index) will get highlighted?

Comment: I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as trivial as it may seem. You have to

1. Make sure that the timing is right. `onResume` will not let you access item views yet, therefore you should use `onWindowsFocusChanged`. Put this in your activity:

   ```
   Handler handler = new Handler();
   int blink = 4;
   int regularBg = android.R.color.holo_orange_light;
   int blinkingBg = android.R.color.holo_orange_dark;

   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       if (hasFocus) {
           final View view = adapter.getViewByPosition(blink, listView);
           view.setBackgroundResource(blinkingBg);
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   view.setBackgroundResource(regularBg);
                   listView.setOnScrollListener(null);
               }
           }, 1000);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Access item views through a custom method you add to the adapter (won't work  through the regular `getView`). It is from over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536/3356270).

   ```
   View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
       final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
       final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

       if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
           return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
       } else {
           final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
           return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that the item you want to highlight is visible under all circumstances. If you cannot guarantee this, because there may be very small devices or the item you want to highlight is further down the list than in the list you show in your question, you will have to scroll to the correct position first. Only after the scroll is finished, you can safely change the item background. Therefore you would have to implement an `onScrollListener` for your `ListView`. For now, until you tell me otherwise, I assume that this is not necessary.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Actually i'm scrolling the view to the right position in onResume();
I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Not exactly how I imagined, but its a good starting point. Thank you for your help.